# How can I make this popup/toolbar in Spyder less disruptive to my workflow?

Tags: python, user-interface, spyder

Sometimes when editing a file in Spyder, a drop-down menu with functions to autocomplete will appear and grab the focus of my arrow keys.

The most reliable way to reproduce this is if I have a function call `foo()` written out in the editor, then realize I need to add the module that contains `foo`. So I arrow key over to the function call and type in `bar.` to get `bar.foo()`. But when I want to arrow key away to the next problem, the function list has popped up and I'm just arrow keying through a list of proposed functions.

I haven't been able to find a way to disable this feature. I tried unchecking every box in Completion and Linting/Completion, but it had no effect. How can I disable this feature, make it pop up after some more specific condition, or otherwise make it less disruptive?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable completions by popping up automatically you can go to `Preferences > Completion and linting > General`> Completions and uncheck `Show completions on the fly`

After that, you only will see the completions if you do the shortcuts (`Tab` or `Ctrl + Space`)

Comment: "Show completions on the fly" is already unchecked, along with everything else in that page. This is in Spyder 4.1.5.

Comment: Could you update to the latest Spyder 4 version (4.2.5) and check again?

Comment: Just updated to 4.2.5 and ensured completion is still disabled. I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: This seems like a bug, could you open an issue?: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/new

Comment: I wound up installing the latest version through pip, fixing the issue